# Find the parametric equations of the following Lines

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Find the parametric equations of the following lines.

a) The line parallel to $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\-1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ and passing through P(1,-1,3).

My solution $\vec{P}$ = $\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\-3\end{bmatrix}$

and for the parametric equation $\begin{bmatrix}2 \\-1 \\0\end{bmatrix}$ + t$\begin{bmatrix}1 \\0 \\-3\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: what is $[2,-1,0]$ a vector?

Comment: You set P in data, then in your solution, with a different value ! and the tangent of your line is not proportional to your guide direction.

Comment: Your answer is wrong. Your line is parallel to $[1,0,-3]$ not to $[2,-1,0]$

Comment: How would i correct it?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner They didn't say the question is given as is

Comment: Start with the equation of a line through the origin. This is just $\vec r(t) = t\vec v$.  Clearly this line is always parallel to $\vec v$ (confirm this for yourself with the definition of parallel vectors).  Then *shift* the line so that the direction is the same but it passes through your point of interest $P$. Then your new equation becomes $\vec r(t) = t\vec v + \vec{OP}$.  (Compare this to the scalar equation: $y=mx+b$). Confirm that this does pass through $P$ and the direction of the vector pointing from any point along the line to any other point along the line is parallel to $\vec v$.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201747/implicit-line-equation/1201812#1201812) will help you further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given the vector $\vec v=[2,-1,0]^T$, all the vectors of the form $[x,y,z]^T=t[2,-1,0]^T$ ( where $t$ is a real number) stay on the same line (1-dimensional subspace) passing through the origin and containing $\vec v$, so this is the equation  of such a line.

You want a line parallel to this one, that does not passes through the origin but through $P=(1,-1,3)$ so, add a vector pointing to this point such that, whan $t=0$, the vector $[x,y,z]^T$ points to $P$ . 
This gives the equation:

$$
[x,y,z,]^T=t[2,-1,0]^T+[1,-1,3]^T
$$