# What is the meaning of transposing a vector in linear algebra quesitons all the time?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am currently taking a course in linear algebra and on a lot of questions have this notation and the more I read about linear algebra online the more I see this notation:

$$2(-1, 2)^T\cdot(4,1)^T=4$$

**Why to the power of T?** I get that it is the transpose and how the transpose works, but why?

Comment: it's a way to write a column vector in one line of text

Comment: what's really true is $2(1, -2)\cdot(4,1)^T=4$

Comment: Recognizing that column vectors and row vectors are the transpose of each other, this might be of interest: [Row vector vs. Column vector](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1198729/139123).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not everybody does it this way, but the idea is that

- the vectors we prefer to deal with, and the vectors we've defined dot products for, are column vectors, like $\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}4 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$.
- the notation $(-1,2)$ and $(4,1)$ denotes row vectors $\begin{bmatrix}-1 & 2\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}4 & 1\end{bmatrix}$.

To get column vectors out of the row vectors, we take the transpose.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, "to the power of T" is actually the transpose. Often people write the transpose of a (column) vector instead of the vector since it takes up less vertical space. It is pure notational convenience and can be useful in inline equations.